# How to position the jQuery Dialog Box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have created this dialog box "**http://jsfiddle.net/xSQr2/**" which by default opens in center of the window.

But I want to open the dialog box right below the button which opens the dialog.

I found the code to do so, here the line of code I added to position my dialog to open right the button :

```
position: {
             my: "bottom",
             at: "bottom;",
             of: $('#addRxOrderButton')
         },
```

But when I added this code, the dialog opens on top of the Button.
Here is the Fiddle with the Position added: **http://jsfiddle.net/xSQr2/1/**

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    position: {
         my: "top",
         at: "bottom",
         of: $('#addRxOrderButton')
     }
```

this means position the dialog's(my) top at the bottom of button

edit : more docs here : http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: Thanks! it works...Also can I add some extra margin on top of Dialog? so there is some space between button and dialog?

Comment: yep just change `at` to `at:"bottom+10"`, 10 here is in pixels. more details on the docs link i posted above.

Answer (score 1):

position worked correctly. You said the dialog bottom to be placed on the bottom of the button.

Use this instead:

```
position: {
 my: "top",
 at: "bottom",
 of: $('#addRxOrderButton')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSQr2/2/

**Update:**

To have the dialog exactly under the button, use this:

```
position: {
 my: "left top",
 at: "left bottom",
 of: $('#addRxOrderButton')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xSQr2/4/

Comment: Thanks! it works...Also can I add some extra margin on top of Dialog? so there is some space between button and dialog?